# How to define that camera is busy by another application using OpenCVSharp4

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I'm using OpenCVSharp4 and It necessary to make a capture from webcam.

But sometimes camera could be busy by another application as Skype, Teams, etc.

I try to use `IsOpened()` method to define that, but it returns true when webcam is busy and makes black capture. (I've used default windows 10 Camera application to make my webcamera busy)

```
        using (var videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0))
        using (var frame = new Mat())
        {

            if (videoCapture.Open(0) && videoCapture.IsOpened())
            {
                if (videoCapture.Read(frame) && !frame.Empty())
                {
                    var image = frame.ToBitmap();
                    return image;
                }
            }
        }
```

Also I've tried to use -1 instead of 0 as a parameter of Open method, but it is totally not working by that way.

Does anybody have an idea how can I deal with that issue, and correctly define that camera is busy?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?